# What is the correct try/except for this error? (SSLCertVerificationError)

Tags: python, django, ssl, openssl

Sometimes I get this error and want to know which expectation I should set to try sending the query again:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='x.x.x', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/x/x/x/x (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError("hostname 'api.exmple.com' doesn't match either of '*.azureedge.net', '*.media.microsoftstream.com', '*.origin.mediaservices.windows.net', '*.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net'")))
```

my code :

```
if 'Content-Type' in header and header['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
    if username and password:
            response = requests.request(http_method, url, json=data, headers=header, timeout=timeout,auth=(username, password),verify=True)
    else:
            response = requests.request(http_method, url, json=data, headers=header, timeout=timeout,verify=True)
```

exemples:

- except ssl.SSLCertVerificationError
- except ssl.SSLError
- except ssl.CertificateError